# How to account for a failed write or add process in Mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

So I've been trying to wrap my head around this one for weeks, but I just can't seem to figure it out. So MongoDB isn't equipped to deal with rollbacks as we typically understand them (i.e. when a client adds information to the database, like a username for example, but quits in the middle of the registration process. Now the DB is left with some "hanging" information that isn't assocaited with anything. How can MongoDb handle that?  Or if no one can answer that question, maybe they can point me to a source/example that can? Thanks.

Comment: How does an _ordinary_ relational db handle that?  Do you mean a relational database runs the operation in a transaction?

Comment: I would only store information after the user completed the registration, not in between steps. If for some reason that is not possible you will need to use compensating actions to revert back (aka delete the data). In the worst case you'll need a scheduled task to clean up orphan data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`MongoDB` does not support transactions, you can't perform atomic multistatement transactions to ensure consistency. You can only perform an atomic operation on a single collection at a time. When dealing with `NoSQL` databases you need to validate your data as much as you can, they seldom complain about something. There are some workarounds or patterns to achieve `SQL` like transactions. For example, in your case, you can store user's information in a temporary collection, check data validity, and store it to user's collection afterwards.

This should be straight forwards, but things get more complicated when we deal with multiple documents. In this case, you need create a designated `collection` for transactions. For instance,

```
transaction collection
{
  id: ..,
  state : "new_transaction",
  value1 : values From document_1 before updating document_1,
  value2 : values From document_2 before updating document_2
}      
// update document 1
// update document 2
```

Ooohh!! something went wrong while updating `document 1 or 2`? No worries, we can still restore the old values from the `transaction collection`.
This pattern is known as compensation to mimic the transactional behavior of `SQL`.